# ImportError: No module named 'environ' with gunicorn on django

Tags: python, django, environ

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with Django 2.0.5 with Django Cookiecutter. I am trying to start a Django server on DigitalOcean and trying to bind gunicorn to 0.0.0.0:8000. python manage.py runserver works fine, but the issue is that it says it can't import environ. Any tips are greatly appreciated, Thanks.

I've ran

> pip install-r base.txt
>
> pip install-r local.txt
>
> pip install-r production.txt

and reinstalled django-environ 0.4.4

**This is the error that I receive when I run the following gunicorn command:**

> sudo gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 config.wsgi:application

```
(venv) root@django-manaland:/home/django/mana/manaland# sudo gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 config.wsgi:application
[2018-05-07 00:12:32 +0000] [20500] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.8.1
[2018-05-07 00:12:32 +0000] [20500] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (20500)
[2018-05-07 00:12:32 +0000] [20500] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2018-05-07 00:12:32 +0000] [20503] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 20503
[2018-05-07 00:12:32 +0000] [20503] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/home/django/mana/manaland/config/wsgi.py", line 38, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 22, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 110, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home/django/mana/manaland/config/settings/production.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .base import *  # noqa
  File "/home/django/mana/manaland/config/settings/base.py", line 5, in <module>
    import environ
ImportError: No module named 'environ'
[2018-05-07 00:12:32 +0000] [20503] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 20503)
[2018-05-07 00:12:32 +0000] [20500] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2018-05-07 00:12:32 +0000] [20500] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

base.py file

```
"""
Base settings to build other settings files upon.
"""

import environ

ROOT_DIR = environ.Path(__file__) - 3  # (manaland/config/settings/base.py - 3 = manaland/)
APPS_DIR = ROOT_DIR.path('manaland')

env = environ.Env()

READ_DOT_ENV_FILE = env.bool('DJANGO_READ_DOT_ENV_FILE', default=False)
if READ_DOT_ENV_FILE:
    # OS environment variables take precedence over variables from .env
    env.read_env(str(ROOT_DIR.path('.env')))

# GENERAL
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#debug
DEBUG = env.bool('DJANGO_DEBUG', False)
# Local time zone. Choices are
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# though not all of them may be available with every OS.
# In Windows, this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#language-code
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#site-id
SITE_ID = 1
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#use-i18n
USE_I18N = True
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#use-l10n
USE_L10N = True
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#use-tz
USE_TZ = True

# DATABASES
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': env.db('DATABASE_URL', default='postgres:///manaland'),
}
DATABASES['default']['ATOMIC_REQUESTS'] = True

# URLS
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#root-urlconf
ROOT_URLCONF = 'config.urls'
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#wsgi-application
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'config.wsgi.application'

# APPS
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DJANGO_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # 'django.contrib.humanize', # Handy template tags
    'django.contrib.admin',
]
THIRD_PARTY_APPS = [
    'crispy_forms',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'rest_framework',
]
LOCAL_APPS = [
    'manaland.users.apps.UsersConfig',
    # Your stuff: custom apps go here
]
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#installed-apps
INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS + LOCAL_APPS

# MIGRATIONS
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#migration-modules
MIGRATION_MODULES = {
    'sites': 'manaland.contrib.sites.migrations'
}

# AUTHENTICATION
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#authentication-backends
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
]
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#auth-user-model
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'users:redirect'
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#login-url
LOGIN_URL = 'account_login'

# PASSWORDS
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#password-hashers
PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/passwords/#using-argon2-with-django
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.Argon2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptPasswordHasher',
]
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# MIDDLEWARE
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#middleware
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

# STATIC
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-root
STATIC_ROOT = str(ROOT_DIR('staticfiles'))
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-url
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    str(APPS_DIR.path('static')),
]
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#staticfiles-finders
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]

# MEDIA
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-root
MEDIA_ROOT = str(APPS_DIR('media'))
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-url
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# TEMPLATES
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#templates
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATES-BACKEND
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-dirs
        'DIRS': [
            str(APPS_DIR.path('templates')),
        ],
        'OPTIONS': {
            # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-debug
            'debug': DEBUG,
            # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-loaders
            # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#loader-types
            'loaders': [
                'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
            ],
            # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-context-processors
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
# http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#template-packs
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

# FIXTURES
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#fixture-dirs
FIXTURE_DIRS = (
    str(APPS_DIR.path('fixtures')),
)

# EMAIL
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#email-backend
EMAIL_BACKEND = env('DJANGO_EMAIL_BACKEND', default='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend')

# ADMIN
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Django Admin URL regex.
ADMIN_URL = r'^admin/'
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#admins
ADMINS = [
    ("""dom""", 'hello@manaland.io'),
]
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#managers
MANAGERS = ADMINS


# django-allauth
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ACCOUNT_ALLOW_REGISTRATION = env.bool('DJANGO_ACCOUNT_ALLOW_REGISTRATION', True)
# https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username'
# https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
# https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
# https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'manaland.users.adapters.AccountAdapter'
# https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html
SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'manaland.users.adapters.SocialAccountAdapter'


# Your stuff...
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

production.py imports

```
import logging

from .base import *  # noqa
from .base import env
```

manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings.production")

    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError:
        # The above import may fail for some other reason. Ensure that the
        # issue is really that Django is missing to avoid masking other
        # exceptions on Python 2.
        try:
            import django  # noqa
        except ImportError:
            raise ImportError(
                "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
                "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
                "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
            )

        raise

    # This allows easy placement of apps within the interior
    # manaland directory.
    current_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(current_path, "manaland"))

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Uhm... I have the suspect that the problem is in the imports in production.py. Could you just copy and paste the imports in `production.py`?

Comment: Hi Karim, I added the imports from production.py

Comment: did you try to run the manage.py shell using the different settings? (qa, prod...)

Comment: Have you tried removing `sudo` in gunicorn command?

Comment: Yes I am using sudo gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 config.wsgi:application and I justed added the manage.py

Comment: Yes I tried it without sudo as well

Comment: I ended up restarting and trying a new virtual environment

Comment: Your virtual environment is missing `django-envrion`, which you need to install with `pip install django-environ`

Answer (score 1):

You need to run your manage.py file with the local settings

```
python manage.py runserver --settings=config.settings.production
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set environment variables for you database :

if you are on linux machine :

```
$ export DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:<password>@127.0.0.1:5432/<DB name given to createdb>
```

cookiecutter doc can help you more for all this :
link : https://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developing-locally.html